# Interaction commands doesn't load

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've been trying to test the command interactions, but it's really weird. The slashcommands take hours to appear, I try to reinvite the bot with the scope, but nothing, the new commands that I added do not appear.

https://github.com/StarQueen342/simple-discord-bot-2024

That's my code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/StarQueen342/simple-discord-bot-2024

I fix it, result discordjs.guide put other code in other archive, well see the readme.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).